# Max Value in split XML using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Anyone able to advice why does my max value return smaller value?

```
DECLARE @SalesYear as nvarchar(max), 
        @SalesPeriod as nvarchar(max)

SET @SalesYear = 2020
SET @SalesPeriod = '5,6,7,8,10'

BEGIN
    DECLARE @Split char(1)=',',
            @X xml

    SELECT @X = CONVERT(xml, ' <root> <myvalue>' +
                             REPLACE(@SalesPeriod,@Split,'</myvalue> <myvalue>') + '</myvalue>   </root>')

    IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#breakdown') IS NOT NULL) 
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #breakdown 
    END

    SELECT T.c.value('.','varchar(20)') breakdown
    INTO #breakdown
    FROM @X.nodes('/root/myvalue') T(c)
 END

 SELECT MAX(breakdown)
 FROM #breakdown
```

It returns max value as '8' instead of '10'. Anything wrong with my code?

Comment: I assume its a string not a number? The ascii value of the char '8' is greater than the ascii value of char '1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the type `INT` instead of `varchar` as `SalesPeriod` seems have a numerical values :

```
SELECT T.c.value('.','INT') AS breakdown INTO #breakdown
FROM @X.nodes('/root/myvalue') T(c)
```

So, string value comparisons `8` will be higher than `10`, You can check :

```
select case when '8' > '10' then 1 else 0 end
```

If you change the type (remove quotes), you will see right flagging.  So, i would recommend to use appropriate datatype.